# How to sign a user out in a micro-service architecture when independent services handle "authentication" and "show user stuff"?

Tags: authentication, vuejs3, microservices, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Update :

1. <s>I think I can solve this using the Cognito [LOGOUT Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html). Still working through implementing this ...</s>
2. Never mind I cannot use the LOGOUT endpoint because I am not using the Hosted UI

My project has one web app that handles authentication that we can call ***Auth Web App*** that will run on its own server in the domain `login.example.com`. This project will have a second web app that shows user data in ***User Web App*** and it will run on its own server in the domain `app.example.com`.

I can successfully authenticate a user in ***Auth Web App*** with AWS Amplify Cognito, persist the JWT Token in a cookie, and redirect the user to ***User Web App***.

As my question states, I am trying to figure out how to sign a user out. I imagine the flow would be the following and **I am stuck on step 3**. I am stuck on this step because I'd imagine ***Auth Web App*** does not know who just got redirected to it.

1. User is on ***User Web App*** and selects the Sign Out Button
2. User is redirected to ***Auth Web App***
3. How does Amplify know who the user is in ***Auth Web App***?
4. Use this Amplify code to sign the user out : `Auth.signOut()`
5. Clear the cookies

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the point with JWT in general is that your Authentication part generates  JWT with limited (usually 1 hour) validity and other applications just verifies it without contacting Authentication part.

That implies the Authentication part is not present in any part of the logic beside logging in, therefore you cannot "sign out" there.

The logging out is done by removing the tokens in the client application.

If the app has any kind of Refresh Token, such token can (and should) be removed from Authentication part first, before removing it from client app. The point is - if you are able to use refresh token, you are able to authenticate (and authorize) yourself. In same way you should authenticate yourself, just instead of generating new JWT access token, the refresh token is deleted from Authentication part.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Are you stating that for "logout" all I have to do is remove the JWT Token cookie from "User Web App"?

If so, then I guess I'd redirect the user back to "Auth Web App" to complete another login.

Comment: @Hokie2014 - you should have clear process what to do, if someone access your page and is not (properly) logged in. When you are logouting person, the same logic should be applied - redirected to some kind of homepage which is accessible for all users or even directly to login screen.
But its not clear from your example how are you keeping people logged-in? Do they have very long-lived token, or do they have to re-login each few hours...?

Comment: @Hokie2014 - but basically yes. If you have just access token, the "logout" means just removing token from client app. If you have also refresh token, then removing refresh token from Auth app and then remove refresh and access tokens from clients app.

Comment: I have not implemented that portion yet, but I was planning on having the Access Token expire after 1 day and the Refresh Token expire after 30 days. I expect this to force the user to re-login every 30 days. Because I am using AWS Cognito, I can set these attributes in my User Pool App Client Settings.

Comment: I'm just confused on how to logout a user. If I understand correctly perhaps I can just remove their JWT Token from the local cache and redirect them to the "auth web app" for login. This would force them to have to re-login to get another JWT Token which is required access the backend API in "User Web App"

Comment: @Hokie2014 - quite often the "refresh token" can be renewed (or used to generate new refresh token), therefore the users are never logged-out if they are coming regularly to your web. The only full loggout happen if they dont appear in 30 days and their refresh token expires. For access token in JWT format, the only way to "logout" user is to delete the token. As I said, you cannot "logout" anywhere as when service checks for access token JWT validity, it uses just public key to verify signature + checks expiration - it does not do anything else, therefore there is no place to "logout".